# Running two SonarQube instances in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: sonarqube, windows-server-2008-r2, multiple-instances

I've already run one SonarQube instance at port 9000 and able access it at address: localhost:9000.
Now I would like to run another SonarQube instance for my new project at port 10000. I've changed in sonar.properties file:

```
sonar.web.port: 10000
sonar.web.context: /
```

However, when I run C:\SonarMAP\bin\windows-x86-64\StartSonar.bat, I got the ERROR message:

```
wrapper  | ERROR: Another instance of the SonarQube application is already running.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I do some research to solve this problem but can't find any helpful information.
Any suggestion ? Thanks !

**UPDATE**

The instance 1 configuration:

```
sonar.jdbc.username=username
sonar.jdbc.password=password
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://server15/sonarQube
sonar.jdbc.driverClassName:                org.postgresql.Driver
sonar.jdbc.validationQuery:                select 1
sonar.jdbc.maxActive=20
sonar.jdbc.maxIdle=5
sonar.jdbc.minIdle=2
sonar.jdbc.maxWait=5000
sonar.jdbc.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=600000
sonar.jdbc.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=30000
```

The instance 2 configuration:

```
sonar.jdbc.username=username
sonar.jdbc.password=password
sonar.jdbc.url:                             jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonarMAP
sonar.jdbc.driverClassName:                org.postgresql.Driver
sonar.jdbc.validationQuery:                select 1
sonar.jdbc.maxActive:                      20
sonar.jdbc.maxIdle:                        5
sonar.jdbc.minIdle:                        2
sonar.jdbc.maxWait:                        5000
sonar.jdbc.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis:     600000
sonar.jdbc.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis:  30000
sonar.web.port:                         9100
sonar.web.context:                        /
sonar.search.port=9101
sonar.notifications.delay:          60
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you can't run multiple instances on Windows because of `wrapper.single_invocation=true` in `conf/wrapper.conf`.

Setting it to false seems to allow this (you'll still have to use different ports as Fabrice explained in his answer) but this is getting into grey zone: non recommended and non tested setup.

Comment: It worked ! But I will consider your non recommended having multiple instance on windows suggestion ! Anw, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You need to change other settings inside the `conf/sonar.properties` file, namely:

- `sonar.search.port`: the port of Elasticsearch
- `sonar.search.httpPort`: if you enabled it in the first instance, you've got to change it as well
- and obviously you can't connect to the same schema of the same DB

Comment: So you mean some duplicate things exist that lead to that error ?

Comment: I've tried change sonar.search.port, however, it still showed error another instance is already running ...